# How use wrappanel in Lightswitch

Tags: custom-controls, visual-studio-lightswitch

i use SilverlightClassLibrary with lightswitch.
i have a error :The type 'WrapPanel' was not found because 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 15 Position: 39]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're missing a reference in your Client project to the toolkit assembly.

If you've never added a rerefernce to a LightSwitch project, you'll need to switch to "File View" (the default view is "Logical view"). There's an icon in Solution Manager to switch between the two views.

Then you'll need to add the reference by right-clicking the Client project, select Add Reference, then navigate to where the assembly is, select the assembly, & click OK.